# Lubuntu keyboard layout toggle hotkey combination

Tags: keyboard-layout, fcitx

I recently upgraded to Lubuntu 15.1 (previously had 14.04) and have installed two keyboard layouts: fr-fr and en-us. I can change between the layouts with `setxkbmap`, but setting the toggle option with `setxkbmap -option grp:super_space_toggle "us,fr"` has no effect.

When I start fiddling with `fcitx-configure` I can't get the hotkey combo I want (super+space) to toggle between my two layouts (fr-fr and en-us). (Did the keyboard configuration utility change with the upgrade?) Here's the screenshot of the dialogue window:

[image: dialogue window]

**Which parameters here do I have to alter?** (note "scroll between input method" options are limited to ALT_SUPER, CTRL_SUPER, ALT_SHIFT, CTRL_SHIFT).

Additionally, when I open a new window or terminal tab, my keyboard toggles layouts (it's not toggled by CRTL_SHIFT btw). **How do I prevent this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; I finally figured out what the (more user-friendly?) input widget from v14 was called: `ibus`. IBUS accepts super+space as language toggle, as well as seems to generally just ... well, work. You define control key combinations and it listens and actually acts upon them (which is more than I can say for fcitx). It's available for v15. See https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/Ubuntu for various installation tactics.

Comment: ibus is an alternative input method framework. It can be simpler and more intuitive, but many input methods, especially for complex languages such as Chinese, are lacking. I agree that fcitx can be a bit hard to grasp in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to find there is "trigger input method", i.e. the very first item in the list. You have to **activate** fcitx first to use any keyboard layouts you selected in fcitx, and scroll through different input methods. Otherwise you'll always be using the default physical keyboard without any layer added on top of it. Pressing that hotkey again deactivates fcitx and returns you to the default keyboard.